# Extract Infopath View

Tags: infopath

Is there a way to extract an infopath view through SharePoint?  Right now, I'm using promoted fields to generate an email, but it would be great if I could just pull the whole view into an email.

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do that when you could just attach the whole form to an email?

Comment: We use InfoPath as browser-based forms, and promote most of the fields we use to SharePoint.  Our current e-mail notifications include property promoted fields from within SharePoint, as the email is generated from a SharePoint Designer Workflow.  Ideally, I'd be able to pull the infopath view through the Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: Never Tested but worth a try.

I have found an msdn blog, whcich could be used to paste the InfoPath form inline with the email, but if you are switching views of your InfoPath form, I am not sure how it might result.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2008/03/18/how-to-display-infopath-forms-inline-with-outlook-email-message.aspx